# Как использовать if повторно?

Tags: python, if

```py
sms = str(input())

if sms == "hi":
    print("hello")
    sms = str(input())
```

На первое hi есть ответ а на второе программа закрывается, можно ли как то оспользовать if повторно?

Comment: Конечно. Вы можете использовать цикл и/или функцию

Comment: Лимита на использование if, вроде как нет. Можно в цикле повторно проверять, можно повторно писать if друг за другом...

Comment: Почитайте о циклах это то что Вам нужно. например while.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы можете использовать if повторно, чтобы повторно проверять условия. Если вы хотите, чтобы программа продолжала работать после выполнения первого условия, вы можете использовать цикл while.

как пример:

```
sms = str(input())

while sms != "quit":
    if sms == "hi":
        print("hello")
    sms = str(input())
```

В этом коде цикл while повторяется, пока значение переменной sms не равно "quit". Внутри цикла if проверяет, является ли sms равным "hi", и, если да, выводит "hello". Это заставляет программу повторно запрашивать ввод, пока пользователь не введет "quit".

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно использовать elif, просто нужно зациклить этот код:

```
while True:
sms = str(input())
if sms == "hi":
    print("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

используй elif

```
sms = str(input())
if sms == "hi":
   print("hello")
elif sms == "bye":
   print("goodbye")
```

Comment: elif можно использовать сколько угодно раз

Comment: какой лимит на `if`? :)